# Reference request: Formula $\chi(D)=2-b$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, riemannian-geometry

it is known that for smooth surfaces D with boundary $\partial D$, the Euler characteristic can be computed as $\chi(D)=2-b$, where $b$ denotes the number of boundary components. I would like to know how to prove this beautiful formula. Does someone know a readable source where I can find it?

Best wishes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is found [here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=UlFbDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA220&dq=Euler+characteristic+of+a+closed+non-orientable+surface+proof&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjb2Juu7qzRAhUOR48KHdmVDdkQ6AEIHTAB#v=onepage&q=Euler%20characteristic%20of%20a%20closed%20non-orientable%20surface%20proof&f=false) and [here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=pZ3HcV9cPOAC&pg=PA108&dq=Euler+characteristic+of+a+closed+non-orientable+surface+proof&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjb2Juu7qzRAhUOR48KHdmVDdkQ6AEIKjAD#v=onepage&q=Euler%20characteristic%20of%20a%20closed%20non-orientable%20surface%20proof&f=false).**

---

For the sake of completeness I will write it down here.

> Since the Euler character of a graph is $2$ and because of the invariance of the Euler characteristic, the equality $\chi =\chi (Q_r) =2-r $ follows from the following proposition:
>
> > Deleting from a triangulation  $K $ an arbitrary triangle and retaining its vertices and sides decreases the Euler characteristic of the triangulation by one.

Hope it helps.